# auto download mp3 in tampermonkey using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, tampermonkey

I want to auto download mp3 when visited on a specific website using Tampermonkey and regex the problem is when I use regex it cannot download the mp3 but when I use normal URL in "var arg" it is auto download the mp3. I want to automatically download the mp3 when visited the website and save the mp3 with the original filename as same the filename on website.

Here is sample url: `http://188.138.xx.xxx/mp3/12/45/song_mp3_6612.mp3`.

Here is my sample javascript

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @include      http://*/mp3*
// @grant        GM_download
// ==/UserScript==

var regex = /^(http:\/\/)(.*)(\/mp3\/.*\/)(.*)$/i;
var arg = { url: regex,
            name: "get the filename from orignal filename in regex.mp3"
          };

GM_download(arg);
```

When I use direct and without using regex it works

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @include      http://*/mp3*
// @grant        GM_download
// ==/UserScript==

var arg = { url: "http://188.138.xx.xxx/mp3/12/45/song_mp3_6612.mp3",
            name: "song.mp3"
          };

GM_download(arg);
```

here is another sample link
here is another link sample: http://62.75.xxx.xx/mp3/5/7e/dj_snake_taki_taki_ft._selena_gomez_ozuna_cardi_b_mp3_17376.mp3 http://188.138.xxx.xxx/mp3/7/d1/rayvanny_ft_diamond_platnumz_mwanza_official_music_video_mp3_19403.mp3
http://188.138.xxx.xxx/mp3/b/52/bad_bunny_feat._drake_mia_video_oficial_mp3_21130.mp3

I tried those regex but the same it cannot find in tampermonkey

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @include      http://*/mp3*
// @grant        GM_download
// ==/UserScript==
var regex = /(\bhttps?:\/\/(?:\d+\.?){4}\/mp3(?:\/[a-z0-9]+)\/[a-z0-9]+\/[.\w+-]+?\.mp3\b)/;
var arg = { url: regex,
            name: "filename.mp3"
          };

GM_download(arg);
```

here is the html element

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
<source src="http://188.138.xxx.xxx/mp3/b/52/bad_bunny_feat._drake_mia_video_oficial_mp3_21130.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think we need to see the code for `GM_download()`.

Comment: it works without using regex but when I use regex is not working. I think there is something wrong with my regex. thanks!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, `GM_download` is a built-in function provided by Tampermonkey.  But this question does need a proper MCVE.

Comment: djsoda, you need to either link to the actual page or **show the HTML structure that contains the mp3.**  You would use the HTML structure, and *maybe* some regex after that, to get the correct URL.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would be going the non-greedy route. You want to consume the least amount possible. You also should look specifically for the file extension `.mp3` at the end of the string to capture.

Then my next observation was the numerous capturing groups - you only need one capturing group to get the entire URL.

```
(https?:\/\/.*?\/mp3\/.*?\/.*?\.mp3)
```

See it at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2ybeRj/2)

My final observation was that you are using string anchors `^` and `$`. In your input string, if the url you were looking for was already immediately after the start of the string `^` and immediately before the end of the string `$` then you wouldn't be needing regex in the first place.

If your URL is always the same format as you provided, then you can even take it one step up:

```
(\bhttps?:\/\/(?:\d+\.?){4}\/mp3(?:\/\d+){2}\/[\w+-]+?\.mp3\b)
```

This will ensure that all the sub folders are there under the folder `\mp3\`, which you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/2ybeRj/5).

Comment: thanks I will try, the filename is differ depend on the song title eg. "http://188.138.xx.xxx/mp3/5/7e/dj_snake_taki_taki_ft._selena_gomez_ozuna_cardi_b_mp3_17376.mp3"